# How to hide PKHUD using UIGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I tried to add a UIGestureRecognizer to hide the HUD when the user touches it. This is my code:

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(someAction(_:)))
PKHUD.sharedHUD.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = true
PKHUD.sharedHUD.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

// ...

func someAction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    // do task
}
```

But someAction is never called when touching the HUD. Any ideas how to hide the PKHUD? I know, there is a HUD.hide() method, but I want the user to decide when the view should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
PKHUD.sharedHUD.dimsBackground: Bool
```